# Simple Products on the cart

Tags: magento-1.7

I've got the following situation on my website:

1 - I search my products based on simple ones (which is alright);
2 - When I click on them my Product page shows me the configurable one (which is alright);
3 - The problem:

When I add one product in my cart and go to the CART page, it is showing the configurable product, which is not the correct.

I'd like to be able to show the chosen simple product instead. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link might prove useful: http://www.ecomdev.org/2012/12/12/magento-checkout-shopping-cart-flow.html

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you have to change the productID which is transmitted to the `CartController::addAction()`

And this is generated (I think) in the JS of the Configurable stuff.

So I think the easiest way is to just add the simple product id (which might be there already) and then remove all the other things from the formular (easiest way, just add `disabled="disabled"` to all the inputs, this doesn't break the JS and avoids the information to be transmitted.

Comment: thanks for your help Fabian, I've sort the problem rewriting the cart/block. Thanks anyway.